# Take out keys and values from dict and store one dict value alone in dataframe

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe

Below is the dataframe which has dict in each column

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {} | {} | {} | {} | 0 |
| {} | {} | {} | 0 | {} |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Each Dict looks like below

```
{ "Name":"abc", "id": "123" ,"add" : "", "prod" : { "a1" : "c1", "a2" : "c2" }}
```

From the above I want the value of  key "Name" in the dataframe, I want to remove id, add, prod keys and its values. So final dataframe should look like the below

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi | ijk | 0 |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 0 | fff |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Please help here

Answer (score 1):

You need a method that handles one cell : retrieve `Name` key is exists

```
def name_extractor(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict) and "Name" in value:
        return value['Name']
    return value
```

---

Then use [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to apply on every cell

```
values = [
    [{"Name": "abc", "id": "123"}, {"Name": "bbc", "id": "123"}, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [{"Name": "cbc", "id": "123"}, 0, 0],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)

def name_extractor(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict) and "Name" in value:
        return value['Name']
    return value

df = df.applymap(name_extractor)
print(df)

     0    1  2
0  abc  bbc  0
1    0    0  0
2  cbc    0  0
```